# Can two questions have the same title?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions

[Concatenating Columns from a Result Set in SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122596/iterating-through-a-result-set-in-sql) and 
[Concatenating Columns from a Result Set in SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122596/concatenating-columns-from-a-result-set-in-sql-server-2000) appear to be the same question. They have the same question id, but different URL.

Is this normal?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259162/can-i-draw-attention-to-a-question-without-placing-a-bounty and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16874/how-to-draw-attention-to-a-question-without-creating-a-bounty?rq=1.

Comment: @NarawaGames: those are not the same title. The titles are similar, but not identical.

Comment: They used to be. It was changed.

Comment: @NarawaGames: I don't see that they were ever the same

Comment: [no they weren't exactly the same](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/259162/1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone edited the title, and there's a little casual overlap.

Comment: Thahks. I did edit the title. I guess the user who pointed out the double URL had the previous URL still.

Answer (score 8):

[Concatenating Columns from a Result Set in SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122596/you-can-make-the-url-say-anything-you-want)

The last part of the URL is just for SEO (and human readability too, I guess).  This is normal for SO-family sites.

Answer (score 4):

Did the user change the url? Also, I think the last / represents a variable value that doesn't really determine the ultimate destination. Perhaps Jeff could tell us what exactly that segment is used for beyond Google-ranking.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the question you referenced...

The question ID is the only part of the URL that identifies the question. The title text after it is just for readability.

For proof, try this link: [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122596/lil-pump-gucci-gang`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122596/lil-pump-gucci-gang)

---

To answer the question you asked in the title...

> Can two questions have the same title?

Answer: Yes? I couldn't find 2 questions with exactly identical titles, but I did find 2 that're a case-insensitive match.

These 2 questions have the same title but different capitalization:

- [why do we need to close questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106139/why-do-we-need-to-close-questions)
- [Why Do We Need to Close Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92580/why-do-we-need-to-close-questions)

Comment: [I wrote a SEDE query for you to find those duplicate titles](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/871654) ...