# Attracting more traffic to Stack Exchange question?

Tags: discussion, bounties, traffic

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to draw attention to a question without creating a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16874/how-to-draw-attention-to-a-question-without-creating-a-bounty)
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)
>   [Best Time to Ask Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/best-time-to-ask-questions)

This question might not be allowed but I am going to try...

I have noticed that asking a question during certain times of the day will elicit much fewer responses then questions asked at peak hours of the day. If I have a question that didn't get much traffic, I didn't get an answer I was looking for, and now is getting towards the bottom of the "Stack" so few people are looking at it, how can I get more traffic to my question? Is there a good way other than offering a bounty? I shouldn't have to sacrifice my points should I?

Comment: This belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: What I find even more amazing is that some languages/technologies get more views during anti-peek times...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16874/how-to-draw-attention-to-a-question-without-creating-a-bounty

Comment: @earlz: "peak" time is different around the world. Some languages have pockets of communities in particular countries where you wouldn't necessarily expect it.

Comment: I've heard that mentioning ponies and waffles will increase traffic - but probably not the right kind!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Word your questions well. If and when new information comes up, or you have a significant improvement to make to your question, edit it, and it will be bumped back to the top slightly. Don't overdo this, of course.

> I shouldn't have to sacrifice my points should I?

Why not? Bounties are a great way to attract attention to a question.

Comment: Is it sometimes appropriate to copy the details of my question and post it to a new question if I am going to add a bunch of new details?

Comment: @Jordan if it's the same question, I would say, usually no. If the question changes due to some new insight or feedback, why not.

Comment: @Jordan @Pekka, also, I'd say it's fair to start a new question if the old one is like a year old, and you can add information to make it not an exact duplicate

Comment: Why not just edit the question with the new information. It will bump to the home page and age is really irrelevant?

Comment: @Diago good point, but I personally would feel very uncomfortable taking the wiki aspect of SO that far, especially if there are responses / discussions in that old question whose context might be destroyed by my edit. I would tend to open a new question and link to the old one instead.

Answer (score 2):

Well you asked a question on Friday which is right on the spot. It's when more people flow in.

Update your question making it more precise. Provide more information on the issue. The quality of the question will rise and so the interest of other people to participate in it. Also each edit brings your question back to the main page.

Another hint which works all the time (not just on Friday). Ask interesting question! Not something that has been asked 50 times before of which 49 were closed as duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

And traffic has nothing to do with responses ;).
1000000 users can check your question but it might be that only 3 ppl respond.