# What do we do with questions that get few views/answers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, unanswered-questions, old-questions

This is to related to my question [Relation Of KeyDown Event With Datagridview's RowHeaderVisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838563/relation-of-keydown-event-with-datagridviews-rowheadervisible).

I have visited many sites and found that most of the topics related to my problem are about edited controls on `DataGridView` like `ComboBox`, `ListBox`, `CheckBox` &c. There is nothing about the main problem. It has to do with the `RowHeaderVisible` property; you can see it by trying.

But unfortunately, once again I have asked a question that received no responses. There have been only four views.

I want to know what we do with important questions that have no answers. Do we just forget about them? Discuss them with other communities, like MSDN?

Comment: @Henk Holterman, Hackery means thieves?

Comment: @Henk Holterman, How do you come to know that i am thief? Clarify it.

Comment: With Hackery I meant low-level tweaking of a UI control. Not stealing.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, I agree with u but think without solve question we can't go ahead. I am not leave incomplete works. it is possible there is my misunderstanding but it will teach me something that is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This general problem has been discussed before, see [How to draw attention to a question without creating a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16874/how-to-draw-attention-to-a-question-without-creating-a-bounty) and [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions).

Questions can be "[tumbleweeded](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed)" for a variety of reasons:

- the question gets asked at a time of day when relatively few users are on the site
- the issue is complicated and nobody knows the right answer (this might be more likely to result in a few hours of silence than permanent unanswered status)
- similarly to the above reason, the problem may relate to an obscure language or technology
- important tags on the question are missing or misleading
- bad spelling/grammar make the question difficult to understand
- the title of the question is misleading or vague
- the question doesn't contain enough information for other users to be able to find a solution

In some of these cases, edit-capable users will fix the problem for you. In others, they'll leave comments that suggest improvements. Sometimes there's nothing they can do, though.

**Okay, now onto your specific case.** I suspect a combination of problems 4, 5 and 6 ("not enough tags" + "language barrier" + "vague title").
I don't know anything about the technology you're using, but I'm sure you can be more specific than just the one tag `[c#]`. I'm guessing you're doing something with a graphics package; perhaps add a tag for that package.
I also can't really understand what you're asking; that's partially because I'm not familiar with the technology and partially the language barrier. I'm not sure that you can do anything about that yourself, though.
Your title right now is just a noun phrase. "Relation of [something]" gives some hints about what you're working with, but it's not as good as something with a verb, like "when I turn on A, then B happens" or an actual *question*, like "how can I do X while setting Y to false?"
Finally, don't forget to use the techniques from the questions I linked at the top of the answer.

I will edit this MSO question after I post this answer, hopefully it gives you an idea of the direction to take.

Comment: thanks for guide me. But where is my point of question which i asked?

Comment: @mahesh, I don't understand what you mean by "where is my point."

Comment: see my question's last two lines.

Comment: @mahesh see my question's first two links.

Comment: That means if this question has no answer than  it will be buried until i have not make an extra efforts on it. wright? if so than we will miss lot's important question.