# How can I make the community leave any response on my post?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've got a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191475/can-i-make-model-validation-system-use-different-css-styles-for-different-kinds) on Stack Overflow. It even has few upvotes. The question has one answer, which I think to be somewhat wrong. Actually later on I've  found a solution which suits me and published it as my answer, though I didn't mark as the answer, hoping to get other responses.

How can I learn why the question has no comments? Even questions tagged as *homework* have comments pointing to question's irrelevance (or something). I would be glad to get comments here mentioning that the question is bad or it is farfetched, or anything. Not espesially to get the points for the question or for the self-answer... just to get someone's view of the issue through comments at least.

I have revised the following topics:

1. [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)
2. [How to draw attention to a question without creating a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16874/how-to-draw-attention-to-a-question-without-creating-a-bounty)

So "bumping" (by editing the question?) or making a bounty... is that it?

Comment: So, are you asking *why* your questions aren't getting responses, or *how* you can attract more responses to your questions? And: poor questions tend to attract snarky comments. Be happy that you don't get them.

Comment: Also: your question received an answer that went into some depth. The answerer was also willing to discuss and revise his answer in response to your comments. That's seriously nothing to sneeze at. Why do you feel that the amount of response you received was "wrong"?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta "Wrong" answer? Because I cannot see the way I could apply it at all. "Wrong" question? Because the solution I found appeared to be very easy.

Comment: Ah. I thought you meant that it was wrong that you got only one answer.

Comment: If the question is worth snarky comments, I'd be glad to here them. Silence is much worse for me

Comment: Useful: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx