# How do I draw attention to a meta post?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta

It's now a week since I have reported [this](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/558/pgn-viewer-menu-is-hidden-behind-the-navigation-bar) bug on Chess Meta, and the question has received only 13 views. I would like to share this question, but I am also afraid this would be considered spamming. Since it is on a meta site, I can't open a bounty. However, this does not seem to be the problem. The problem is that not much people visit Chess Meta. Nothing posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16874/how-to-draw-attention-to-a-question-without-creating-a-bounty) can help, because the question is already on the top of the [list](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com). The bug is very annoying to me. Some even don't know it is a bug.

How do I draw attention to this question, without causing chaos to the community?

Comment: The developers are going to see it regardless of what you do.  Getting any attention from anyone else is going to have no effect on it being fixed, so there's not really much point bothering trying to get such attention.

Comment: I don't think the developers would take it seriously if only one user complains about it. I hope I am wrong though. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that the company is having a holiday right now (or so I'm told) so at the earliest in January someone might attend to it.

Comment: @rene I hope so.

Comment: We need to keep these tools functioning, so we do want to fix them, you just caught us at a bad time - it's a holiday this week. Now, that's not to say we would have fixed it in a week otherwise - with 170+ sites and a lot of new work happening right now, it can still take us some time to get to bug reports like this. I've added it to a list of things to triage, though, so it should get fixed. Sorry I can't make any guarantees on when.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Monica Cellio's answer to [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306397/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unfixed-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-without) clearly explains how to get attention for per-site meta issues.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the developers see all the bugs anyway so there is not much point getting more attention for it as it is not a discussion, support or feature request.

You could try post it on the site’s chat room to draw attention. This way more people will see it and if they upvote it, it will appear in the hot meta posts section.

Answer (score 1):

The developers will view all bug reports and fix them when necessary. In your case, there is no need to draw more attention as it already has/will get all the needed attention to fix it. However, with [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions, you may need to draw attention through [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). If you know other users that may be interested, you can contact them via email or another way of communicating. The one thing you should *never* do is post the exact same question again. It will be closed as duplicate, flagged as spam, and probably deleted.

Answer (score -1):

The closest we have to an official answer, for such a bug/feature request, is (para-phased): Employees don't really look at meta - so [use everything, including email & Twitter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317011/what-are-the-effective-communication-channels-for-effecting-change-to-se/317221#317221), to get their attention.

Basically, you can get 100s of SE users to see and upvote your request - and nothing will come of it because it will take an Employee to champion it (I do mean *champion* not just acknowledge). So do what you can, which is not much, to put it on their radar as much, and as many ways, as you can.

Granted, if you are not much of a Twitter user or don't really like Medium for blogging it might not have as much impact - and the chance of **chaos** because, once again, change will come from outside the SE network is definitely possible - but it will at least up your chances and really the ignoring of meta doesn't leave much of an option.

*I really appreciate Adam's response to this in the comments, but will leave it up because I still think it is worth mentioning (particularly using the contact us/email if it is a major bug)*

Comment: Tim's post covers feature requests more than anything. He's right in saying that meta hasn't scaled well overall, but in the absence of another tool, we do monitor metas for bug reports and they get prioritized relative to each other. I was on Q&A bug duty when the particular report that prompted this post came in, but unfortunately I didn't have a chance to properly review it (or, honestly, any other that came around that time) before the company closed up for the holidays. My current plan is to catch up on that in January and/or bribe the next person on duty to take a look in my stead.

Comment: @AdamLear until I begin to see results, real results not the same repeated messages, from meta - I'm not going to trust it as a platform

Comment: That's fair. What sort of response or activity do you envision when you say "real results"?

Comment: As far as features, I think that's been covered (over-covered). When it comes to bugs, I used to use the mobile app/mobile site quite heavily (vs. desktop) when I researched or taught and any bug report I saw was quickly met with "we don't support these products we made". Yes, I get that the responsive design is suppose to alleviate most of these but I **hate** how it was done (SE's process not actual coding/look) but that message tells me - don't even bother putting in a bug report. Combine this with the great need for tooling features being ignored and I'd take anything besides the standard

Comment: ....standard response from the same people (including yourself), who are really trying but lost all my faith that they can actually effect change at SE. For instance, it is you - not any other developer - who responded to this - just having a different developer say "we see it, sorry for the delay, we will add it to the next/a later build" would be helpful (yes, you were "on duty" this time but I'm speaking in general). Particularity, the simple apology - cause I still have not seen any apology from SE except for with the same 3-4 people. I don't know if even that is even enough now @AdamLear

Comment: FWIW, which I know ain't much, I also think that the situation we're in with the mobile apps is particularly unfortunate. But either way... that makes sense, thanks for the response.

Comment: @AdamLear it is worth me staying with SE. Really the efforts of you, Jon, Tim, and the others who respond and deal with user issues is currently the only reason I don't remove my SE accounts, Even if a fair amount of my anger and frustration at SE as a whole leaks through (okay, probably more than "fair") I really do appreciate the effort.

Comment: Cute ninja puppies are worth hanging around for as well though, right? ;)

Comment: heh, and the Python chatroom (even if I've been avoiding all that recently)  and its regular motley crew @JonClements, of course