# why do we need to close questions?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Do We Need to Close Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92580/why-do-we-need-to-close-questions)

This is pretty much duplicate of (minus the suggestion that people can abuse closing questions - though I suppose they could):

[Why Do We Need to Close Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92580/why-do-we-need-to-close-questions)

But I thought maybe we could have at least one version of this question that is not closed.

A starter:

- There are downvotes
- Most questions are viewed and answered as they are new
- Its stifles people learning
- Often appears offensive and aloof (especially to new users)
- If you don't like "opinion" type questions you can always stick away from them

A good explanation of why a question is bad is far more useful to the original asker..

I can see where the logic of signal-to-noise arguments come from but are there any stats on site usage that shows how people find questions to answer that actually supports this? As in if 90% of questions viewed and answered are from people looking at the latest questions this would have no affect.

Does it mean that the various K.P.I's about the place (both on your account and on the site as a whole) would no longer be representative?

(Note: if you can find an open version of this question anywhere please link to it.. I looked & asked - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106135/where-is-the-original-question-this-quesiton-was-closed-as-a-duplicate-of)

P.S. If there are no discussion type questions allowed here either, I am sorry for offending you.. But it would appear to me that arbitrarily discursive questions (on all stack exchange sites) are left open, maybe as anyone with the authority to close it finds it interesting.  leaving us with no clear idea on where you can post discursive questions.

P.P.S As a side note some of those discursive questions are very interesting and good learning - we have some experienced and knowledgeable users here, I personally love to read there opinions

Comment: Simpler to reopen a closed question than to ask an exact duplicate and look for even more answers.  Don't be surprised if both are downvoted further and closed/deleted though.

Comment: I cannot re-open a question though ;-) and I was expecting a bunch of abuse + downvoting etc ... tis the SO way

Comment: LOL this exactly why the system has issues.. i have to create a question lose rep and have it closed to get another question re-opened.. however the extra specific info i am looking for is now lost and no-one will add any new responses to the original question..

thanks you @bill the lizard though for re-opening the other one and I am not having a dig at you in any way..

Comment: [How do you reopen a closed question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question) If you feel like the FAQ does not cover it good enough, feel free to comment on the FAQ.

Comment: @Straitjacket I don't know how you can comment on the FAQ, the link you provided is to a question on meta.. and I the reason I cannot re-open a question is because I don't have the rep, which is unlikely to change ;-). Thanks though

Comment: Becouse of questions like this one...

Comment: @Ian Ringrose I am hoping that was an ill thought through joke and not further evidence that SO reputation is inversely proportional to imagination.  There was no open question for this and it appears to be directly the exact type of question meta is made for. If you think that closing questions is a good idea then put forward some well thought through argument. this question was closed and the other re-opened:good. the specific points and approach to the question and the answers being looked for are not the same, is it good that those are now lost? is the system perfect?

Comment: There's the [`FAQ`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)-Tag here on Meta, which keeps over a hundred questions under one umbrella, and provides additional guidance to advanced topics, like this one. The question I linked to should cover this topic. If you feel like something is missing in *that question*, comment on that question.

Comment: to be honest i should never have posted this question as "this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." sorry

Answer (score 6):

> A good explanation of why a question is bad is far more useful to the original asker.

[image: Duplicate Example]

---

[image: Offtopic Example]

Comment: lol that's the best answer I have ever seen on here! i am upvoting you for style not content ;-) - oh poo i don't have the rep to upvote you, and if you give it five mins i am sure my rep will be lower ;-)

Comment: I don't see why that is actually of benefit though (to close the question), equally an answer could have been posted pointing out its a duplicate, linking to original post. then you could down vote the question for good measure. the question being asked in different terminology is actually of benefit to people searching on SO.

Comment: Questions are closed to keep people from splitting up between them, and/or encouraging behavior which is not desirable.

Comment: I can see where you are coming from.. that is the most if not only valid reason i can think of, but I think that there are other things that mitigate that: you can upvote the link to the original, you can downvote the duplicated question, plus people could see the comments and answers linking to the original so could choose not to answer.  basically I don't see anything that justifies the major liberties that are taken when someone can say "your question is not valid"

Comment: one mans repeated question is another mans new insight ;-)

Comment: i got the rep to give you that upvote i owe you now..